# Quantum mechanics video lectures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

Are there any good video lectures for learning quantum mechanics at the level of Griffiths?

Comment: Note that res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE and they usually do not distinguish between on-line and off-line resources.

Comment: Related meta post: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11319/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. **Please note
>   that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly
>   discouraged by [the site's policy on resource recommendation
>   questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)**.
>   This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet have
>   commentary.

- Here are a set of [31 lectures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcmGYe39XG0&list=PLE0334305C5C04C30) by Prof. Balakrishnan given to undergraduates.
- Susskind has done a load of quantum mechanics videos aimed at beginners: Lecture 1 | Modern Physics: Quantum Mechanics (Stanford) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h1E3YJMKfA